# How to automatically scroll a web page before page load in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I was using top scroll in one of my projects.

So following is my urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?i)$','project.views.home', name="home"),
url(r'^(?i)all/$','project.views.about', name="about"),
url(r'^(?i)blog/$','project.views.blog', name="blog"),
url(r'^(?i)contact/$', 'project.views.contact', name="contact")
```

Now, I have a banner in page below which there are 3 categories about , blog and contact.

When i open the page home the banner is shown below which 3 categories are shown and "about" is shown hovered(like bold text with an underline). Now when i click on about, the page scrolls up just below the banner. Following is the JS code i used for it:-

```
if((urlPath.match(/\/all//i)))
 {
 $(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.banner').height()}, 400);
        });
 }
```

P.S: banner is the class name which contains image

Now the categories part comes to top of the page.

Now what i want is the if i select blog or contact they are autoscrolled to the top, like currently if in the above if condition i give the parts for blog and contact , the scrolling happens again. Any help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could give all your links a common class and data attribute like:

```
<a href="..." class="scroll-link" data-scroll-to="ID_of_element_you_want_to_scroll_to">...</a>
```

then you can use this when the page loads:

```
$('.scroll-link').click(function() {
    var scrollTo = $(this).data('scroll-to');
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + scrollTo).offset().top}, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: I want this to be scrolled only once. For example say I click on about, the page should be scrolled, now say i click on blog the div should be fixed to top and scrolling should not happen. I think i have to use a fix panel for categories and change content below else it wont work:)

Comment: ah, may be you should provide a visual sample of the current situation so we can assess and help. It seems I didn't really understand your situation.